How to deal with changes in Power BI dimension tables?
I have a Power BI data model (star schema) with a Dimension customer table and a Fact Sales table.
I want to be able to analyse historically which locations had which sales. How would I deal with a customer moving addresses? The product might have been sold to a customer living in Berlin, but now that the customer lives in New York, Berlin has been overridden.


If you are in control of the 'Berlin' being overwritten, the common solution to that problem is to implement whats called a slowly changing dimension.
Its described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension
The customerId would be a new one, with the change of address, in your case.
If you have no control over the source tables, I dont see a way for you to solve this
HTH
Jens
